# Selenium hangs in loop

Tags: loops, selenium, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

I'm using Selenium's Python bindings for a quick scraping job, but have found that for whatever reason, the Firefox WebDriver becomes unresponsive after precisely nine iterations.

Basic operation consists of loading a page, selecting a state from a dropdown menu of all fifty, clicking through to the results page and then returning to select another state. Irrespective of where I start in the list of states, after iterating through nine pages, the Firefox WebDriver becomes unresponsive, though no errors are thrown.

Code in question below:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

def set_up(url):
    driver = webdriver.Firefox()
    driver.get(url)
    return(driver)

def search(driver):
    for i in range(1, 49):
        element = driver.find_element_by_id("StateList")
        all_options = element.find_elements_by_tag_name("option")
        print("Acquiring data for" + str(all_options[i].get_attribute("label")))
        all_options[i].click()
        driver.find_element_by_id("SearchButton").click()
        #scrape page components here
        driver.back()

url = 'http://www.example.com/'

driver = set_up(url)

search(driver)
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: my guess is that when you execute `driver.back()` on the 9th iteration, your app doesn't end up where you think it's ending up.

Comment: Looked into it, but not in this case, as `driver.back()` can be replaced with `driver.get(url)` and the problem persists.

Comment: I'd try stepping through manually, see if the same behavior is exhibited when done outside of Selenium.

Comment: Stepped through manually, no problems

Comment: Can you try running it against chrome or IE?  Are you running Firefox 25?  If you are, you may need to downgrade to FF 24 until a new version of selenium is released.

Comment: @Richard, ran it against Chrome and it worked without any issues. The issue may have been FF 25, as you pointed out.

Comment: I've read that there are frequently issues with latest releases of Firefox and Selenium until Selenium catches up.  I'd recommend running tests on Firefox 24 using Selenium 2.37, and waiting for Selenium 2.38 to run tests on Firefox 25.

Comment: Right. Do you know if it's possible to maintain two FF versions concurrently? I may just do the testing in a VM to keep things simple..